# Is the following form of functional components valid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pretty new to React here. Thus far, I've only been using components that either take no arguments or props. Then, I always render the component using the form `<SomeComponent {...props}/>`

However, I came across a situation where I didn't even realize that some of the functions I was creating were actually functional components since they were returning JSX. However, they were visibly different from the way I'm used to making and using components. It looked something like this:

```
  const MoneyExample = (category, amount) => {
    if (typeof amount !== "number" || typeof category !== "string") {
      return;
    }
    return (
      formatter.format(amount) !== "$0" && (
        <>
          <h4>{category.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + category.slice(1)}</h4>
          <p>{formatter.format(amount)}</p>
        </>
      )
    );
  };
```

and then rendering it inside another component using like this

```
{MoneyExample("Budget", someAmount)}
```

instead of the more common form

```
<MoneyExample budget={"Budget"} amount={someAmount} />
```

I've tried looking around for info, but I'm not even really sure how to phrase the question. Is this type of thing against React's principles or completely fine? Are there any other considerations or notable differences between these two? Sorry if this is obvious to some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{MoneyExample("Budget", someAmount)}
```

When you do this, `MoneyExample` is not being used as a component. It's being used as a helper function. The code inside `MoneyExamples` executes immediately, and then its return value is used. In contrast, the `<MoneyExample` version tells react you want a `MoneyExample` with certain props, but `MoneyExample` doesn't actually get called just yet (it usually gets called very soon after)

In very simple cases this will work ok, but as soon as you add in hooks you'll start running into trouble. As far as react can tell, those hooks are part of the component that's *calling* `MoneyExample`, not part of `MoneyExample` itself. You will therefore be forcing yourself to obey the rules of hooks, which means `MoneyExample` must be called exactly the same number of times on each render.

Additionally, doing it this way also means you can't make use of React.memo to skip rendering. The function must always execute, even if nothing changed.

---

In short: I recommend you stick to creating components that accept props, and then create elements using the JSX syntax.

```
const MoneyExample = ({ category, amount }) => {
  // ...
}
<MoneyExample budget={"Budget"} amount={someAmount} />
```

Comment: Is it also okay to keep some of these simple components that are only used in one place inside the same file as its parent or should you always separate components into their own files no matter what?

Comment: That's a personal preference thing. I've been on teams that require a strict separation of one component per file. But personally, i think some cases make more sense to keep together, just to make clear that they're closely related, and not really meant to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

you can't just return, but you can return `null`.

```
const MoneyExample = ({category, amount}) => {
  if (typeof amount === "number" || typeof category === "string") {
    const value = formatter.format(amount);
    if(value !== "$0") {
      return (
        <>
          <h4>{category.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + category.slice(1)}</h4>
          <p>{value}</p>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

and you should use:

`<MoneyExample budget={"Budget"} amount={someAmount} />`

the include via function can have some strange behaviour on rerendering of components.

https://griffadev.medium.com/just-a-friendly-reminder-that-react-isnt-really-just-javascript-don-t-nest-functional-components-a6a822dddd

Comment: Weird, my code seems to be working. When you say I can't, do you mean that it's bad practice? Doesn't return just return undefined anyway?

Comment: https://griffadev.medium.com/just-a-friendly-reminder-that-react-isnt-really-just-javascript-don-t-nest-functional-components-a6a822dddd

Comment: yes, but returning undefined is more a bad practice. typescript will notify you about it.

Comment: Gotcha. It was working for me with the first syntax, but when I changed it to the conventional React element style it threw an error.

Comment: you are only allowed to send 1 prop to a component, as `({category, amount})` does, but you had it without `{}`. That would be a invalid component.

Comment: That's because in my case, I wasn't using props. I was using regular arguments and the first syntax, which has been established as not a good approach